# Lumen Eloquent Php database

Tags: php, database, dropdown, lumen

I am trying to do a dropdown whit data from the database using laravel. I am doing the drop down whit city and state. I am getting the items from the database but I can't show only the citys in that state.

```
$app->get('/register', function() use($app) {
    $judete = $app->judet->orderBy('nume', 'ASC')->get();

    $localitati = $app->localitati->where('parinte', '14 ')->orderBy('nume', 'ASC')->get();

    $app->render('auth/register.php',[
        'localizare_judete' => $judete,
        'localizare_localitati' => $localitati
    ]);
})->name('register');
```

The view:

```
<div>
    <label for="judet">Judet *</label>
    <select type="text" id="judet" name="judet" onchange="getid(this.value);">
        <option value="">Alege judet</option>
        {% for judet in localizare_judete %}

        <option value="{{ judet.id }}">{{ judet.nume }} </option>

        {% endfor %}

    </select>

    {% if errors.first('judet') %} {{errors.first('judet')}} {% endif %}
</div>

<div>
    <label for="oras">Oras *</label>
    <select type="text" id="oras" name="oras" >
        <option value="">Alege Oras</option>

        {% for localitati in localizare_localitati %}

        <option value="{{localitati.nume}}">{{ localitati.nume }} </option>

        {% endfor %}

        {% if errors.first('oras') %} {{errors.first('oras')}} {% endif %}
      </select>
    </div>
```

Comment: in this line  $localitati = $app->localitati->where('parinte', '14 ')->orderBy('nume', 'ASC')->get(); where "14" is i need to get the value of option value under judet.

Comment: This looks like Lumen, not Laravel. Please update your tags and title of the question

Comment: It seems like you forgot a `</select>` at the end of your HTML code.